# snapshot.numChildren is not a function in a Realtime Database trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using google cloud functions in my Firebase app.
I have a method to count the comments in a post and update a property called `comments_count` in the post.

It was working just fine until I upgraded the firebase console and its dependancies. Now, in the log it's saying `commentSnapshot.numChildren is not a function`

The code in the function looks something like this:

```
  //Function that updates comments count inside post
  exports.setCommentsCount =
      functions.database.ref('/Comments/{post_id}').onWrite((commentSnapshot, context) => {

        const post_id = context.params.post_id;
        const commentsCount = commentSnapshot.numChildren();

        //rest of code here
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should familiarize yourself with the [breaking changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database) that occurred in the 1.0 version of the Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK for Realtime Database triggers.

[onWrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite) triggers no longer receive a DeltaSnapshot as the first argument to the function you provide.  It's now a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) object with `before` and `after` properties, each of which is a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot) object.  This DataSnapshot has a numChildren method:

```
functions.database.ref('/Comments/{post_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const post_id = context.params.post_id;
    const commentsCount = change.after.numChildren();
}
```

Comment: After almost an hour of searching and that was it. Thank you very much 

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. You're getting this error because `numChildren()` is a DataSnapshot interface but snapshot is not a DataSnapshot.
Here's the correct code :

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const MAX_USERS = 10;

exports.truncate = functions.database.ref('/chat').onWrite((change) => {
  const parentRef = change.after.ref;
  const snapshot = change.after

  if (snapshot.numChildren() >= MAX_USERS) {
    let childCount = 0;
    const updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      if (++childCount <= snapshot.numChildren() - MAX_USERS) {
        updates[child.key] = null;
      }
    });
    // Update the parent. This effectively removes the extra children.
    return parentRef.update(updates);
  }
  return null;
});
```